# Drag and drop multiple child node

Tags: asp.net, jquery-selectors

I had populated data in ASP.NET TreeView control. How will I drag multiple child nodes from a TreeView and drop the dragged nodes one to a DIV or any portion, using JQUERY ? I know in jquery, there are methods "draggable" and "droppable" to make this possible. But I want to drag multiple child nodes and drop it.

Answer (score 0):

drag drop is not possible with asp.net treeview control

Answer (score 0):

Use Telerik RadGrid for drag and drop